# Can I make a constructor in C++ of different data types?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

I have a class which has multiple data members of different data types. I was wondering if I can create and initialize an object using a constructor.

```
class test
{
     public:
            int a;
            string b;
            float c;

      test (int x, string y, float z);

};


int main()
{

    test t1(10,"Hello",2.5f); //this line doesn't work

}
```

Comment: _"I was wondering if I can create and initialize an object using a constructor."_  - that's basically the sole reason constructors exist ;) Please add some more details to your question to clarify _what exactly_ is not working. You only declared the constructor, but never defined it in the code shown. You also didn't include `<string>`.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Please show a more complete example and the exact error you are getting.

Comment: oh damn, my bad i completely forgot to define the constructor, i keep forgetting to define them and think that the values will automatically get assigned, i should have assigned the values inside the constructor, thanks @churill stupid mistake on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that *it doesn't work* is not really what we do on StackOverflow. You should provide an error message.

With that said, I suppose you are getting an error from the linker because your constructor does not include a definition, but only a declaration.

Here's a working example: https://godbolt.org/z/r89cf86s3

```cpp
#include <string>

class test
{
public:
    int a;
    std::string b;
    float c;

    test (int x, std::string y, float z) : a{x}, b{y}, c{z}
    {}
};


int main()
{
    test t1(10, "Hello", 2.5f);
}
```

**NOTE** Passing `std::string` by value to the constructor can lead to temporary objects being created, so to keep the workings of this code and improve it, you could use a const-reference, i.e. `const std::string&` as parameter of the constructor.

Comment: Just got it thanks, also i never knew that we could assign the values like a{x}, b{y} and so forth, so thanks again

Comment: @Free-Man [I hate to be that guy, but...](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20hate%20to%20be%20that%20guy%2C%20but...) this will cause unnecessary temporaries.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili "Often secretly means, "I love to be that guy", " :P

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili because of the `std::string` not being passed as const reference you mean? Is there any other?

Comment: @Victor yes, that one. You could also take-by-value-and-move. That'd also avoid the extra copy.

Comment: I saw it straight from the beginning, but wanted to keep the spirit of the original code.

Comment: @Victor nothing wrong with your answer. Just wanted to let the OP know that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *implement* the constructor `test (int x, std::string y, float z);` Don't forget to `#include <string>` at the top of your source file.

Although you could use the notation

```
test t1{10, "Hello", 2.5f};
```

which will cause the arguments to be assigned to the class members in the order they are written; although you will have to drop the constructor completely.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have *declared* the constructor, but never *defined* it.

```
class test
{
public:
    int a;
    std::string b;
    float c;

    test(int x, std::string y, float z) : a(x), b(y), c(z) {}
};


int main()
{
    test t1(10, "Hello", 2.5f);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to define the constructor :(

it should've been like this:-

```
class test
{
     public:
            int a;
            string b;
            float c;

      test (int x, string y, float z)
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
        c=z;

     }

};
```

int main()
{

```
test t1(10,"Hello",2.5f); //this line doesn't work
```

}

Comment: We've all answered that, yes :)

Comment: @Bathsheba You [can](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4vjxboedn). Objects are not const within their own constructors/destructors.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, sorry, senior moment. I'll put the real reason up.

Comment: Using base member initialisation is preferred in constructors in order that `const` members can be set.

Comment: when you write "should be like this" you put the bar a little higher and not using the member initializer list doesn't pass for me. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-lists